# Controlling division of workload between parallelized MKL, openMP and MPI

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, mpi, cluster-computing

I am trying to learn MPI for HPC applications, using Fortran. I have a question regarding the distribution of workload when I have a code that is parallelized for single node computation using libraries like MKL or openMP.

Say I have a cluster with 8 nodes each containing 32 cores. If I were to compile my code on a single node and run without MPI I see that MKL and openMP both use the full 32 cores available to them, as desired. I am wondering if I were to now compile `program` for the MPI cluster and run using `mpirun -np 8 program`, may I then expect that each MPI process represents a unique node? In other words, would I then have 8 processes running my program in parallel, all with 32 cores available to them to be used by MKL and openMP? Or do I need to do more to enforce this behaviour.

Thanks!

Comment: Doing `mpirun -np 8` starts 8 processes, and one hopes with 8 nodes they will nicely be spread out. However, that does depend on how well your mpirun script is written. Much depends on which specific MPI you have. Do you need to give it an explicit hostlist or have you specified the existence of your nodes otherwise? But basically, yes, you've understood it correctly.

Comment: This is (generally) a two steps tango: First you need to start 8 MPI tasks with 4 cores each (and ideally bind each MPI task to its 4 cores). Then you should ideally ask the OpenMP runtime to bind the 4 OpenMP threads to its cores. A common pitfall is each MPI tasks is allocated a single core, and OpenMP threads end up time sharing.